# A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I have following type definition

> [Symbol(level)]?: string;

I have tried

importing level from winston and change the type to string|symbol but it doesn't resolve the problem.

It keep giving me following error
"A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type."

any clue? any pointer is helpful

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your symbol `level` needs to be defined as a `unique symbol`, like so:

```
const level: unique symbol = Symbol();
```

Then modify your interface like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
    [level]?: string;
}
```

Comment: Whoa. I was wanting to do `[typeof level]?: string;` because `level` is a runtime value, and we want the type. Weird.